# concat 2 list in angular / js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two "lists".
The first, array that contains only codes, and looks like this:

```
[10, 50, 75, 88]
```

The seconds, list that contains all codes + means that possible, and looks like this:

```
[
  {  
    code: 10,
    name: 'example 10'
  },
  {
    code: 50,
    name: 'example 50'
  },
  {
    code: 60,
    name: 'example 60'
  },
  {
    code: 66,
    name: 'example 66'
  },
  {
    code: 75,
    name: 'example 75'
  },
  {
    code: 88,
    name: 'example 88'
  }
]
```

I would like to attach the interpretation from the second list, for each item of the first array.

For example, the result should be:

```
[
  {  
    code: 10,
    name: 'example 10'
  },
  {
    code: 50,
    name: 'example 50'
  },
  {
    code: 75,
    name: 'example 75'
  },
  {
    code: 88,
    name: 'example 88'
  }
]
```

or:

```
['10- examle 10', '50 - example 50', '75 - example 75', '88 - example 88']
```

I prefer the first version but also the second version good enough...
how can i do it?

Comment: The first one is an object not array. No idea what *"attach the interpretation"* means. Show example of expected results. How is this being used? May even be able to access directly from the view also

Comment: The first one is array. I wrote it with the indexes... maybe its confused.

Comment: Then update question with all the proper details if you want help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want, for every item in the input list, to find the name corresponding to the matching code, I would suggest converting the spec/mapping array into a `code: name` object.

For example using [.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) array methods (check the links for polyfills if you need to support IE8-):

```js
var list = [10, 50, 75, 88]
var spec = [{"code":10,"name":"example 10"},{"code":50,"name":"example 50"},{"code":60,"name":"example 60"},{"code":66,"name":"example 66"},{"code":75,"name":"example 75"},{"code":88,"name":"example 88"}]

// convert spec to {"10":"example 10", ...}
var spec_obj = spec.reduce(function(previous, current) {
  previous[current.code] = current.name
  return previous
}, {})

var annotated = list.map(function(item) {
  return item + ' - ' + spec_obj[item]
})

console.log(annotated)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That exactly what I was looking for!